# Why are "percent" and "%" not printed in this Python code ? How can I fix it?

Tags: python, formatting, decimal, percentage

The following does not display "%" and "percent" as expected:

```
def percent (birds,counted):
    percent =  (birds/counted)*100
    return percent


counted = 10
birds= 5
print ("sparrows ", birds,"=",("{:.2f}".format(percent(birds,counted),"percent")))
print ( birds," sparrows = ",("{:.2f}".format(percent(birds,counted) , ("%"))))
```

How can I get these to show?

Comment: small thing you should be careful of: you're shadowing your function name with a variable (percent). I think this is fine in your case, but you should avoid doing this to avoid confusion and unexpected behaviour

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Congratulations on your first post. What have you tried? Add your code and any errors/output to your question and that will help others find solutions to your problem. It may be helpful to you to read: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It would help if you provided an example of the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

To print the % sign you need to 'escape' it with another % sign:

```py
percent = 12
print("Percentage: %s %%\n" % percent)  # Note the double % sign
>>> Percentage: 12 %
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include the percent symbol or text in your string, like so:

```
counted = 10
birds= 5
print ("sparrows ", birds,"=",("{:.2f} percent".format(percent(birds,counted))))
print ( birds," sparrows = ",("{:.2f}%".format(percent(birds,counted))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have enoughs places in your strings if you wish to have all arguments consumed by `.format`, i.e.

```
def percent (birds,counted):
    percent = (birds/counted)*100
    return percent

counted = 10
birds= 5
print ("sparrows ", birds,"=",("{:.2f}{}".format(percent(birds,counted),"percent")))
print ( birds," sparrows = ",("{:.2f}{}".format(percent(birds,counted) , ("%"))))
```

output:

```
sparrows  5 = 50.00percent
5  sparrows =  50.00%
```

I also suggest taking look at so-called [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) if you are working with python 3.6 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

try this one, I hope this will help you.

```
def percent(birds, counted):
    birds = int(birds)
    counted = int(counted)
    percentage = '{0:.2f}'.format((birds / counted * 100))
    return percentage

birds= 5
counted = 10
print("sparrows", birds, "=", percent(birds, counted), "percent")
print(birds, "sparrows","=", percent(birds, counted), "%")
```